# ¿Cómo enviar un enlace de canal de Telegram con la foto del canal?

Tags: telegram

Hola tengo un problema y esque cuando mando este enlace,

```
https://t.me/pumpcoinsfree
```

o este otro

```
https://t.me/joinchat/AAAAAEZZbcnamiq_aGpDqQ
```

No me aparece la foto del canal, Como puedo mostrar la foto del grupo tal que asi.
http://prntscr.com/k6guqk

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta está incompleta y así es imposible responder. Debes decir qué tecnología, API, lenguaje de programación estás usando y mostrar cuál es el código que falla.

Comment: Jesus Te sugiero realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask] es importante, lo que preguntas ya existe en el sitio: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91748/mostrar-video-thumbnail-en-lugar-de-imagen-estática-al-compartir-enlace